# How do I keep HTML change in browser?

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, web

I'd like to know how to keep my html changes in my browser. For example, I open Google chrome and click inspect element on a webpage, and change some values, every time I refresh the values go back to what they were before, I want to know how to refresh and make the webpage keep the values! thanks very much

Comment: you can't. if you're hitting refresh, you're telling the browser to fetch a fresh copy from the server. by definition you're TELLING the browser to throw away your changes.

Comment: if you want to make css changes on your local project, there are many chrome extensions. google for "live css" or something similar...

Comment: Can I make it "fake refresh" instead then?

Comment: You could write a userscript to make changes after page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't as refreshing means fetching the server's copy of the page which doesn't know about your modifications.

You could always save the entire source of the page locally and work on it from there.
However it would only ever be a local copy.